# Dart/Flutter - File Posted to PHP Server is Zero bytes in size

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, http-post

I'd like to post an audio file to a PHP page on my server. Although the file pretends to upload, it's size is zero bytes.  Here's the method I'm calling;

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http_parser/http_parser.dart';

Future<String> uploadAudio() async {
  final serverurl = "http://example.com/audiotest2.php?";
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(serverurl));
  var multiPartFile = await http.MultipartFile.fromPath("audio", filepath, contentType: MediaType("audio", "mp4"));

  request.files.add(multiPartFile);      
  request.send().then((result) async {http.Response.fromStream(result)
        .then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200)
      {
       print('response.body '+response.body);
      }
      return response.body;
    });
  });
}
```

Here's the php at the backend, I realize this code is insecure, but it's just temproary as I'm not great with mysql and just need to keep it simple to get it working. I'm using the PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3 Pear Package to get file contents. It worked ok when I was using App Inventor instead of Dart/Flutter;

```
 <?php 
header("Content-Type: audio/mp4");
require_once (dirname(__FILE__).'/PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3/Compat/Function/file_get_contents.php');

    $data = php_compat_file_get_contents('php://input');
    $audioname = 'Test.m4a';

    if (file_put_contents($audioname,$data)) {echo "File Saved";} else {echo "File not Saved ";} 
    if (filesize($audioname) != 0) {echo " Recording Saved.";} else {echo " File size zero.";}      
    ?>
```

The error I'm getting in the Android Studio console is;

```
 response.body File not Saved  File size zero.
```

The Test.M4a file appears on my server but is empty with zero bytes. But there are no errors showing in the PHP error logs on my server.

I'm guessing there is an incompatibility somewhere between how it's sent and how it's received but I'm a beginner and not sure where it is.

Any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the PEAR package was a waste of time. The function already exists right within PHP, so;

```
<?php 

header("Content-Type: audio/mp4"); 

    if (isset($_FILES["audio"]) && $_FILES["audio"]["error"] == 0) {
    $uploaddir = '/mynewdirectory/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['audio']['name']);   
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
    } else {echo "Upload failed";}          
    } 

?>
```